# Converting to C style String

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, reverse

I'm trying to create a function that takes in a string, the reverses it, which is all being done in main. Here's what I have so far.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


std::string str = "zombie";


void Reverse( std::string a)
{

    char* a1 = a.c_str;
    char* a2;

    for (int i = (strlen(a1) -1); a1[i]!=0; i--)
    {
        a2 += a1[i];
    }

    str = a2;
}

int main()
{
    Reverse(str);

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

But i keep getting this error. I can't utilize pointers in this question. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I'm particularly having issues with converting the inserted parameter a into a c-style string.

EDIT 2: So I started cleaning it up a bit, to my understanding, the code that I had wouldn't accomplish my goal at all, even with proper changes. Would this be on a better track? I plan on just converting the string to c-style before passing it to the function.

```
void Reverse(const char* s)
{
    int x = strlen(s);
    std::string str = "";

    for (int c = x; c > 0; c--)
    {
        str += s[c];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is entirely invalid.

For example the parameter should be declared as `std::string &`.

It is a bad idea when the function depends on a global variable.

In this statement

```
char* a1 = a.c_str;
```

there are at once two errors. First of all instead of `a.c_str` there must be `a.c_str()`. And the member function `c_str` returns a constant pointer.

This pointer

```
char* a2;
```

has indeterminate value.

So as you till now know nothing about how the function can be written in C++ then I'll just show several variants of its implementation.

The simplest one is the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string & Reverse( std::string &s )
{
    s.assign(s.rbegin(), s.rend());

    return s;
}


int main()
{
    std::string s = "zombie";

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << Reverse(s) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The function uses reversed iterators of the `class std::string`.

Another approach is to use the standard algorithm `std::reverse` declared in the header `<algorithm>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::string & Reverse(std::string &s)
{
    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "zombie";

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << Reverse(s) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to write the function yourself using a loop then its implementation can look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


std::string & Reverse(std::string &s)
{
    for (std::string::size_type i = 0, n = s.size(); i < n / 2; i++)
    {
        //std::swap(s[i], s[n - i - 1]);
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n - i - 1];
        s[n - i - 1] = c;
    }

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "zombie";

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << Reverse(s) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In all three cases the program output looks like

```
zombie
eibmoz
```

You can also try to write the function yourself using iterators (either bidirectional or random) instead of indices.